# How do I add a correctly formatted link (with a hash mark) to an email message using intent on Android?

Tags: android, email, hyperlink, android-intent

I am creating an email intent and filling the message with a link that contains a hashmark:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)#Software_development");
```

Once I send this and reopen it on Android, the default mail client only makes the link to `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)`

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with Android's default mail. Links work great using the gmail app!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I am unable to test my code because of problem in my IDE.

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/html");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)#Software_development"));
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I tried what you suggested, but I still am getting the same error.